# __cyg_profile_func_enter equivalent for Visual Studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, profiling

I have code that implements profiling using:  `__cyg_profile_func_enter` and I am trying to port this to Windows to compile using VS2010. I looked around and Microsoft asks for premium or ultimate versions to perform profiling and that too in a different manner.

Is there an equivalent to the gcc profiling functions in Visual Studio or are there any opens ource libraries that implement these?

Comment: Are you trying to implement the same kind of profiling `gprof` does - i.e. sampling only the program counter, and counting calls between functions, and post-processing it to try to get a graph?

Answer (score 2):

See the options:

- [/Gh (Enable _penter Hook Function)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c63a9b7h.aspx)
- [/GH (Enable _pexit Hook Function)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc11y76y.aspx)

You'll need to write some x86 or x64 assembler function that knows about the x86 style stack layout to get the return address. A more complete example is in [DIY MS Visual C++ Function Profiling using /Gh Compiler Option](http://www.fengyuan.com/article/profile.html)